# CakePHP 3 Rss error

Tags: cakephp, controller, rss, components, cakephp-3.0

i want do a rss, I followed this http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/rss.html. But the things not working correctly, because when access the router of the rss, it returns a controller error, saying that controller does not exists. My route is this:

```
/posts/index.rss
```

When do this request, it return a error of the controller not found.

```
The action index.rss is not defined in PostsController
```

I declared that "app" to accepts rss..My complete config/routes.php

```
use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
Router::defaultRouteClass('Route');

Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {

    Router::extensions(['json', 'xml', 'rss']);
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Fronts', 'action' => 'index']);
    $routes->connect('/contact', ['controller' => 'Fronts', 'action' => 'contact']);
    $routes->connect(
        '/:controller/:action/:id-:slug', 
        [], 
        [
            'pass' => ['id', 'slug'], 
            'id' => '[0-9]+',
            'routeClass' => 'DashedRoute'
        ]
    );

    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});

Plugin::routes();
```

I also made the LoadComponent in :: initialize () of the controller

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
}
```

And my controller

```
class PostsController extends AppController
{
    ...
   public function index()
   {
    ...
        if($this->RequestHandler->isRss()) :
            $_rss = $this->Posts->find()->limit(20);
            $this->set(compact('_rss'));
           return;  
        endif;
    ...
   }
}
```

Whats is wrong?

Thankss..!!!

Comment: Really `/plosts/index.rss`? shouldn't it be `/post/index.rss`?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong :) ... is /post/index.rss

Comment: You placed `Router::extensions('rss');` in `/config/routes.php`? Any other error messages in `/logs/`? Did you create a view file in `src/Template/Posts/rss/index.ctp`?

Comment: Yes, put it...Router::extensions(['json', 'xml', 'rss']);

Comment: The view also was created...only gives error not found the controller...in my debugger->Request show this

plugin(null)
controller Posts
action index.rss
_ext(null)
pass(empty)
isAjax(false)

_ext should be _ext(xml) or _ext(rss) ?

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not sure with this: Have you also added the response class `use Cake\Network\Response;` in the controller after declaring the namespace? (and maybe request class as well)

Comment: Please show your complete `config/routes.php` file.

Comment: `Sorry, I wrote it wrong :) ... is /post/index.rss` - you don't have  post controller, so unless you have a route defined for that url it'll be a 404. It is better to show a problem, than describe it - helps identify typo problems like that - or to ignore them as irrelevant if there's evidence that the right url is being requested.

Comment: @user1843159 I add  <pre>use Cake\Network\Response;</pre>, but still have the same error...

Comment: @AD7six my controller to rss should be     /posts/index.rss  :)

Comment: @ndm Now I add all code of my config/routes.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining the extension the wrong way, `Router::extensions()` is ment to define global extensions for all routes that are being connected *after* `Router::extensions()` has been invoked.

So, inside a scope, the call to `Router::extensions()` is too late, as it's the `Router::scope()` method, that, when invoked, reads the global extensions and passes them into the scope.

Either invoke `Router::extensions()` outside of the scope

```
Router::extensions(['json', 'xml', 'rss']);

Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    // ...
});
```

or use `RouterBuilder::extensions()` inside of the scope (note that this overrides the global extensions that the scope might have been inherited)

```
Router::scope('/', function (\Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml', 'rss']);
    // ...
});
```

See also **[Cookbook > Routing > Routing File Extensions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routing-file-extensions)**

Comment: Thanks guy...this solved my problem...And now I understand the problem...very, very good... :)